# how do i display double digit numbers in lc3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm creating a code to calculate the area of a rectangle. I have done the multiplication but it only displays digits 0-9. My professor said in order to display 2 digit numbers I need to subtract 10 in a loop and count how many times the loop occurs. I tried it out and it isn't working can someone assist me.

```
.ORIG x3000
AND R3, R3, #0 ;r3 stores the sum, set r3 to zero
AND R4, R4, #0 ;r4 is the counter
LD R5, INVERSE_ASCII_OFFSET ;inverse ascii offset
LD R6, DECIMAL_OFFSET ;decimal offset
;---------------------

;storing first input digits
LEA R0, display1 ;load the address of the 'display1' message string
PUTS ;Prints the message string
GETC ;get the first number
OUT ;print the first number
ADD R1, R0, #0 ;store input value(ascii) to r1
ADD R1, R1, R5 ;get real value of r1

;storing second input digits
LEA R0, display2 ;load the address of the 'display2' message string
PUTS ;Prints the message string
GETC ;get the first number
OUT ;print the first number
ADD R2, R0, #0 ;store input value(ascii) to r2
ADD R2, R2, R5 ;get real value of r2
;----------------------

ADD R4, R2, #0 ;fill counter with multiplier
MULTIPLICATION:
ADD R3, R3, R1 ;add to sum
ADD R4, R4, #-1 ;decrease counter by one
BRp MULTIPLICATION ;continue loop until multiplier is 0
;----------------------

;Product in R3
AND R1, R1, #0 ;r1 will hold -10
AND R2, R2, #0 ;r2 = 10's counter
AND R4, R4, #0 ;r4 = 1's counter
AND R5, R5, #0 ;r5 will hold the answer
LD R1, NEG_TEN ;r1 = -10
ADD R5, R3, #0 ;copy answer to r5

Loop1
ADD R5, R5, R1 ;Product - 10
BRn EndDec
ADD R2, R2, #1 ;increment 10's counter by 1
BRnzp Loop1
;----------------------
LEA R0, stringResult
PUTS
ADD R0, R3, R6 ;move result to r0
OUT ;print result
HALT
display1 .STRINGZ "\nenter the length: "
display2 .STRINGZ "\nenter the width: "
stringResult .STRINGZ "\nArea: "
INVERSE_ASCII_OFFSET .fill xFFD0 ; Negative of x0030.
DECIMAL_OFFSET .fill #48
NEG_TEN .fill #-10 ; -10
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at how it works for a single digit:
If R0=4, then we add '0' to it. 4 + '0' = '4', which is something we can print.

Now imagine R0=14.  When we do 14 + '0' we get '>' (ascii 62).  Not what we want at all!  We need to consider each character at a time.  That means we need to generate an algorithm that first prints '1' then prints '4'.  From before, we know how to do 1->'1' and 4->'4', so the problem now becomes "how can we turn 14 into 1 & 4".

Thinking about positional number systems, we know that 14 = 1x10^1 + 4x10^0.  Moving to a three digit number, we see that 142 = 1x10^2 + 4x10^1 + 2x10^0.  Looking at these facts, we can see that 142/100=1, 142/10=14 and 142/1 = 142.  This is the first step and we can see how to use it to extract our first digit.

But this doesn't help us with the further digits.  However, remembering that division has a buddy, modulus, we can see that we can perform 142/100=1 and 142%100=42.  Taking this one step further, we notice that 42/10=4 and 42%10=2.  So now we've turned 142 into 1 4 2, which we already know how to turn into '1' '4' '2'.

Of course, LC3 doesn't have divide and modulus functions, but that's a solvable problem that I'll leave up to the reader.